# Jmeter JMESPath extraction with Partial text or contains filter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, response, jmespath

Hello can someone help me simulate this scenario. Because I want to use contains or Partial text on my filter using JMESPath extractor on Jmeter.

Sample Response:

[{
"orgName": "MNL_Automation",
"name": "Test-123",
"agentMap": {
"25b08b79-d2e6-3313-bf39-8d1a8bf318d5": "DATABASE",
"9af282a5-1d13-3050-8912-ab29275f215d": "BUSHIDO APPLIANCE",
"4013a43f-0ea2-3df0-8fc3-9e562a7f82c7": "APACHE TOMCAT",
"a51df66c-7b0d-30b8-85db-03605246aecf": "AD SERVER"
}
},
{
"orgName": "MNL_Automation",
"name": "Test-132",
"agentMap": {
"25b08b79-d2e6-3313-bf39-8d1a8bf318d5": "DATABASE2",
"9af282a5-1d13-3050-8912-ab29275f215d": "Testing APPLIANCE",
"4013a43f-0ea2-3df0-8fc3-9e562a7f82c7": "APACHE TOMCAT",
"a51df66c-7b0d-30b8-85db-03605246aecf": "AD UAT"
}
},
{
"orgName": "DEPARTMENT 2",
"name": "BUSHIDO",
"teams": "{"APPLICATION_ADMIN":"30084152-5ddc-3079-a765-dbbcd58f2391"}",
"agentMap": {
"c1716dcd-5181-3e9e-ac05-0e0cc48b0789": "AD SERVER"
}
}
]

Response Screenshot:

[image]

Expected Result:
Will Extract all agentMap values with the name starts with **Test**

[image]

Currently I'm just using exact filter but it returns me single filter and I want to use Partial text/Contains to make my the script more flexible. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it's possible to achieve with JSON JMESPath Extractor as JMeter's implementation doesn't strictly follow the [JMESPath specification](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with), however it should be possible to get it with [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be something like:

```
$..[?(@.name =~ /Test.*/)]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)